# Parsing SemVer in Scala

Tags: scala, parsing, parser-combinators, semantic-versioning

I'm trying to write a SemVer (http://semver.org) parser in Scala using parser combinators, as a sort of familiarisation with them.

This is my current code:

```
case class SemVer(major: Int, minor: Int, patch: Int, prerelease: Option[List[String]], metadata: Option[List[String]]) {
  override def toString = s"$major.$minor.$patch" + prerelease.map("-" + _.mkString(".")).getOrElse("") + metadata.map("+" + _.mkString("."))
}

class VersionParser extends RegexParsers {
  def number: Parser[Int] = """(0|[1-9]\d*)""".r ^^ (_.toInt)
  def separator: Parser[String] = """\.""".r
  def prereleaseSeparator: Parser[String] = """-""".r
  def metadataSeparator: Parser[String] = """\+""".r
  def identifier: Parser[String] = """([0-9A-Za-z-])+""".r ^^ (_.toString)

  def prereleaseIdentifiers: Parser[List[String]] = (number | identifier) ~ rep(separator ~> (number | identifier)) ^^ {
    case first ~ rest => List(first.toString) ++ rest.map(_.toString)
  }

  def metadataIdentifiers: Parser[List[String]] = identifier ~ rep(separator ~> identifier) ^^ {
    case first ~ rest => List(first.toString) ++ rest.map(_.toString)
  }
}
```

I'd like to know how I should parse identifiers for the prerelease section, because it disallows leading zeros in numeric identifiers and when I try to parse using my current parser leading zeros (for e.g. in "01.2.3") simply become a list containing the element 0.

More generically, how should I detect that the string does not conform to the SemVer spec and consequently force a failure condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some playing around and some searching, I've discovered the issue was that I was calling the `parse` method instead of the `parseAll` method. Since `parse` basically parses as much as it can, ending when it can't parse anymore, it is possible for it to accept partially correct strings. Using `parseAll` forces all the input to be parsed, and it fails if there is input remaining once parsing stops. This is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of completeness I'd add

```
def version = number ~ (separator ~> number) ~ (separator ~> number) ~ ((prereleaseSeparator ~> prereleaseIdentifiers)?) ~ ((metadataSeparator ~> metadataIdentifiers)?) ^^ {
  case major ~ minor ~ patch ~ prerelease ~ metadata => SemVer(major, minor, patch, prerelease, metadata)
}
```

method to *VersionParser*